# QT 4.5.2, QTableView is not editable

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I just add a new QTableView to my form, set the model and configure it, but i cant edit cells. In other table there is no problems with editing. Whats wrong with me? Code:

```
void MethodicWorkWidget::setupMethod3Model() {
    method3Model = new ExtSqlModel(this);
    method3Model->setTable("methodworks3");
    method3Model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);

    int typeInd = method3Model->fieldIndex("typeid");
    method3Model->setRelation(typeInd, QSqlRelation("methodworks3types", "id", "Name"));
    method3Model->setFilter("teacherid="+QString::number(teacherID));//+" AND YearID="+QString::number(yearID));

    method3Model->setHeaderData(typeInd, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Вид"));
    method3Model->setHeaderData(method3Model->fieldIndex("discipline"), Qt::Horizontal, tr("Дисциплина"));
    method3Model->setHeaderData(method3Model->fieldIndex("theme"),      Qt::Horizontal, tr("Тема"));
    method3Model->setHeaderData(method3Model->fieldIndex("date"),       Qt::Horizontal, tr("Дата проведения"));
    method3Model->setHeaderData(method3Model->fieldIndex("value"),      Qt::Horizontal, tr("Балл"));

    ui.label_2->setText(QString::number(teacherID));

    method3Model->setSort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);

    //populate and check
    if (!method3Model->select()) {
            QMessageBox::critical(NULL, tr("Ошибка обращения к базе"), tr(
                            "Произошла ошибка при выборе руководства:\n")+manageModel->lastError().text());
    }

    ui.method3View->setModel(method3Model);
    ui.method3View->hideColumn(method3Model->fieldIndex("id"));
    ui.method3View->hideColumn(method3Model->fieldIndex("teacherid"));
    ui.method3View->setItemDelegateForColumn(typeInd, new QSqlRelationalDelegate(ui.method3View));
    ui.method3View->resizeColumnsToContents();

    connect(ui.method3AddButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(method3Add()));
    connect(ui.method3DelButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(method3Del()));
    ui.method3DelButton->setEnabled(method3Model->rowCount()!=0);

    if(UserInfo::role() == UserInfo::Guest){
            ui.method3AddButton->setEnabled(false);
            ui.method3DelButton->setEnabled(false);
            ui.method3View->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    }
```

}

Comment: Actually, the model decides whether the table is editable, not the view. Please show the code of `ExtSqlModel` class.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov sorry, dont know how to add code, post it here: http://pastebin.com/y3Z08rbG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certain index is editable if `QAbstractItemModel::flags` result includes `Qt::ItemIsEditable` flag. `QSqlRelationalTableModel` is editable by default but you override `flags()` and disable editing when the condition `!index.column() < realColNum-2` is not satisfied. It seems that you have an error in that condition. Note that `!` operator has higher priority than `<`. You probably want `index.column() >= realColNum-2`. Also check `realColNum` value.